# Riemann Roch Theorem with genus 1 curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following PDF, RIEMANN-ROCH THEOREM ON COMPACT RIEMANN SURFACES, is written by FEI SUN. But I do not understand why **all functions such that $(f)+p \ge 0 $ are constants(and why we cannot find functions having poles of order 1 at $P$ and no other poles.)**
[image]

Here is my thought : because of $1= l(P) =\dim \mathcal{L}(P):=\left\{f \in K(C) : (f) \ge -1\cdot P \right\}$ and
$$(f) = \sum_{p}\operatorname{ord}_p(f)\cdot P \ge -1\cdot P....... (*) $$

$(*)$ means that sum of number of poles and number of zeros is greater than or equal to $-1$. Here, how to get the result that  $(f)+P$ should be constant?

By guesswork, Since $l(P)=1$  $\mathcal{L}(P)$ is generated only one basis. Hence, the constant line comes to mind. But It would not be not helpful to solve my question...

**Edit** : Is it a good example? :  in $\mathbb{C}^1$ take $p=0=0+i0$ :

1. take $f=1/z$, ( $z=x+iy, x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,) then $f=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}dy$, which is generated by two basis ( real part, $dx$ and imaginary part, $dy$).
2. Next,  if $f=z=(z-0)^1=x dx + ydy$, it is still generated by real and imaginary part. and
3. if when we consdier the funtion $f$ whose sum of poles and zeros is greater than $-1$, for example, something like $f=z(z-2)^2/(z-1)$, or $f=(z-1)/z(z-2) , $ then like two cases, we expect that such funtion $f$ is decomposed by real and imaginary part.

Hence, if $l(p)=1$ (or under the given condition $(*)$), the function f cannot contain variable $z$ part , and such function $f$ would be only constant function.

Furthermore,  on your comment, when considering the dimension $l(P)$ would be *at least* $2$, in $\mathbb{C}^{1}$, in case of $C^{1}$, the maximal basis is $2$. Meanwhile, $\mathbb{C}^{n}(n\ge 2)$, I think that the dimension *any other functions* you would indicate would be differen. Maybe $l(p) \ge 2$, hence I think that you mentioned *at least* $2$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use photos in place of text because text in images doesn't get indexed and does not appear in search results. But I suppose it's fine here, since you have enough keywords in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$l(P)=1$, so the space of functions having no more than a simple pole at $P$ is 1-dimensional. But the constant functions obviously satisfy this requirement, so if there were any other functions, the dimension $l(P)$ would be at least 2.

Comment: I try to add comment here, but since the lack of space, I add the additional comment on the **Edit** part.

Comment: @HanwoongCho When people talk about the dimension $l(P)$, they are talking about complex dimension! There should be no real or imaginary parts mentioned at all. Moreover, the theorem is stated for complete complex curves, so you shouldn't be thinking about $\mathbb{C}$, which is an affine curve, not a complete one, and $\mathbb{C}^n$, which is not a curve at all.

Comment: Then, instead this post's question, I think that it is better what is a basis of $L(D)$, frankly speaking , I have not sincerely thought about *which elements* consist of a basis of $L(D)$. I think that I should learn about this in detail or upload new question (if I do not understand this... )